# How to run Runtime.exec() in Elasticsearch Plugin Environment?

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am writing a plugin for Elasticsearch which essentially receives a string and sends it to a PHP script to analyze it and get it back in a JSON format.  To do this, I originally had something similar to this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php5");
```

I could process the output with a BufferedReader.

However, when I call this code within the Elasticsearch plugin framework, I get this:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program \"php5\": error=13, Permission denied"
```

I have already given the plugin execute permission for the security manager.  What could I be doing wrong?

**[Edit from comment]**

Permissions:

```
pedro@pedro-desktop:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/php lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 14 21:56 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php 
pedro@pedro-desktop:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/php lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 14 21:56 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php5 
pedro@pedro-desktop:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/php5 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9381192 Oct 27 21:56 /usr/bin/php5
```

Comment: Here are the permissions for php

`pedro@pedro-desktop:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 14 21:56 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php`

`pedro@pedro-desktop:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 14 21:56 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php5`

`pedro@pedro-desktop:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/php5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9381192 Oct 27 21:56 /usr/bin/php5`

Comment: Put permissions code from comment